# Is each plgpsql stored procedure a transaction?

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency, locking, plpgsql

I couldn't find anywhere where this was defined, so looking to you all for help.  I have a long-ish running stored procedure (5 seconds) in plgpsql, but needed to place a lock inside for a particular section, so was planning on using a pg_advisory_xact_lock.  But I obviously don't want to lock for the entire 5 seconds, so am wondering if I break up the stored procedure into 2 or more stored procedures - one main one that calls the others, how does that work with transaction locks?  Does each stored procedure count as a transaction, so the lock would end when that stored procedure is finished (committed)?  Or does the entire chain of stored procedure calls count as one transaction?

i.e.  if I have

```
procedure A
   call procedure B
   call procedure C
end
```

If I put a transaction lock inside procedure B will it unlock before procedure C starts?  Or will it lock until procedure A returns?

Thank you for any help or pointers to where I can find this info.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your stored procedures contain `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`, procedure A and all procedures called from it will run inside a single transaction.

It is ok to run transactions that long in exceptional cases, but if that is the normal case, you won't be happy with your database.

If you use advisory locks, you can release the lock at any time (`pg_advisory_unlock`), so there is no need to hold the lock until the transaction ends.